# Sort MATLAB array in descending order

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I am using MATLAB. I have a question about how to sort an matrix in descending order along one column of a matrix and have the rest of the row values follow suit.

For example,

```
A = [1 30; 2 40; 3 10; 4 50; 5 20]
```

becomes

```
B = [4 50; 2 40; 1 30; 5 20; 3 10]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the SORTROWS function, specifying that you want to sort using the *second* column in *descending* order...

```
B = sortrows(A, -2);
```

Here, the 2 means "sort in column 2," and the negative sign in front of the 2 means "in *de*-scending order."  See [the MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) for more information.