# Matlab sort matrix depending on two columns in descending and ascending

Tags: matlab, sorting

I would like to sort a Matrix of three columns first depending on the third column ascending and if there is a tie it should be sorted descending depending on the value of the first columns. For example

```
A=
    745 30  0.9
    421 60  0.8
    374 29  0.9
    358 32  0.9
```

Should change to

```
A= 
    421 60 0.8
    745 30 0.9
    374 29 0.9
    358 32 0.9
```

Using sortrow(A, [3,1]) I can only get the matrix sorted in ascending order. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This answer could be of help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18820228/4806927). Try `B=sortrows(A,[-3 -1])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose whether the column is sorted ascending or descending depending on the sign of the column number.

As per the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html#bt8bwzx-1-column), negative values cause a given column to be sorted descending.

> **Column**: Column sorting vector, specified as a nonzero integer scalar or a vector of nonzero integers. Each specified integer value indicates a column to sort by. **Negative integers indicate that the sort order is descending.**

So you want

```
B = sortrows( A, [3, -1] );
```

---

If you want to be more explicit, you can use the `direction` flag, as noted by Sardar in the comments. This gives the same result, but has only been available since R2017a<sup>(1)</sup>:

```
B = sortrows( A, [3, 1], {'ascend', 'descend'} );
```

(1): [2017a docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017a/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) show this functionality, [2016b docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2016b/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) show only the `mode` flag which sets *all* sorting to either ascending or descending and is not column-specific.

Comment: or use the [`direction`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html#bt8bwzx-1-direction) flag

Comment: @SardarUsama The positive/negative functionality is backwards compatible, `direction` was introduced in R2017a so must have slipped my radar! I've updated the answer accordingly.